# Equivalence of different metrics on orbit space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, group-actions, isometry

Let $(M,\mu)$ be a Riemannian manifold with an isometric action of a compact Lie group $G$. If the action is not free, the orbit space $M/G$ is a stratified space
\begin{equation}
M/G = \bigcup_{H<G} M_{(H)}/G
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
M_{(H)}:= \{ x\in M \,| \, G_x = g H g^{-1} \text{ for some } g\in G\} 
\end{equation}
This is a submanifold of $M$. Consider another submanifold contained in $M_{(H)}$ defined by,
\begin{equation}
M_H := \{ x \in M \,|\, G_x =H \}
\end{equation}
Both $M_{(H)}$ and $M_H$ inherit a Riemannian metric from the ambient manifold $M$.

The slice theorem tells us that the orbit space $M_{(H)}/G$ is a manifold. Denoting $\pi_{(H)}: M_{(H)} \rightarrow M_{(H)}/G$. Then the isomorphism,
\begin{equation}
 d\pi_{(H)} : (T_x{(G\cdot x)})^{\perp M_{(H)}} \xrightarrow{\cong} T_{\pi_{(H)}(x)}(M_{(H)}/G)
\end{equation}
can be used to define a Riemannian metric on the orbit space, denoted by $\mu_{(H)}$, turning the projection into a Riemannian submersion.

On the other hand, on the submanifold $M_H$, we have the action of the group $N_G(H)$ which is the normaliser of $H$ in $G$ (maximal subgroup of $G$ in which $H$ is a normal subgroup). Then the quotient group $L:=N_G(H)/H$ acts freely on $M_H$ and $M_H/L$ is a manifold as well. We can define a metric $\mu_H$ on $M_H/L$ to make the natural projection map from $M_H$ into a Riemannian submersion.

Now as manifolds, we have a diffeomorphism
\begin{equation}
M_H/L \cong M_{(H)}/G
\end{equation}

**Question:**

1. Are the Riemannian manifolds $(M_H/L, \mu_H)$ and $(M_{(H)}/G, \mu_{(H)}) $ isometric?
2. If not, then are there some group actions where the above are isometric? One trivial case is when $H<G$ is a normal subgroup in which case $M_{(H)}=M_H$